# Замена стандартной галереи

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Задача - написать приложение, которое будет отображаться в окне выбора приложения для просмотра картинок в Андроид и сразу же возвращать Uri определенного файла. Пробовал создавать пустую активити с различными `intent-filter`, но ничего не помогло. Можете подсказать правильное решение?

Comment: для какого именно интента вам нужен интент-фильтр?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage), activity, которое должно ловить intent для открывания изображений, надо объявлять так:

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <data android:type="image/*" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <!-- The OPENABLE category declares that the returned file is accessible
         from a content provider that supports OpenableColumns
         and ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor() -->
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Для более тонкой настройки этого момента можете изучить [манифест системного приложения галереи](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: добавьте ссылку на источник, буду благодарен.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei обновил ответ